# Intersection of curve $x'=0$ with orbits of a dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let us suppose I have the following dynamical system
$$
x'=f(x,y)\\
y'=g(x,y)
$$

The curve $x'=0$ which is not an orbit of the system will intersect orbits at critical points (where $x'=0$ and $y'=0$). Is there a general way to analyse where else the curve $x'=0$ will intersect the orbits of the system

Comment: No, because this is literally the general form for any system of two variables that is differentiable.

Comment: Ok thx. Can I say that along that curve, $x''=0$ which would imply $\partial f/\partial y=0$ and by iteration $\partial^n f/\partial y^n=0$

Comment: The orbits are described by $y'=\frac{g(x,y)}{f(x,y)}$. If we impose $f(x,y) = 0$ then ...

Comment: The curve defined by $x'=0$ is not an orbit, it's just some line in the phase space which intersects orbits, but I'm searching where it does it.